# TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null

Tags: react-native, webpack

i have a ready mobile app with react native @0.48.3 and inside it i am going to bundle a web app with webpack but i get this error when running webpack i guess it's a problem with versions but i can't find which one's is causing this error :

```
   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null
    at Scope.moveBindingTo
```

here is my package.json file

```
   "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-dom": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.48.3",

    },
  "devDependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
  "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
  "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source": "^7.2.0",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
  "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
   "babel-jest": "^21.0.2",
  "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
  "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.1",
  "jest": "21.1.0",
  "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.47.0",
  "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
  "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
  "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
  "webpack": "^4.28.4"
 },
 "jest": {
 "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

and here's my babel.config.js

```
 module.exports = {
    presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset","@babel/preset- 
    env"],
    plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread","@babel/plugin- 
    transform-react-jsx-source","transform-es2015-block-scoping"]
  };
```

Comment: FWIW, at this point, `babel-jest` is no longer necessary as it is merged into `jest` and [should probably be removed from one's package.json](https://github.com/babel/babel-jest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your package.json script, ensure you are using the **`@babel/env`** not `--presets=env` as in last version.

```
"scripts": {
 "build": "babel ./src --out-dir ./build --presets=@babel/env",
}
```

This is the important part `--presets=@babel/env`